# Converting XML to JSON using R XML

Tags: json, xml, r

I am trying to convert XML to JSON using R. Its not giving the right JSON output. Online converters are giving a different formatted JSON output. Any suggestions on an alternative approach.

**library(RJSONIO)**

**library(XML)**

**a<-xmlToList(xmlfile)**

**b<-toJSON(a)**

Comment: What's the "right JSON output"? What's the input?

Comment: converting XML to JSON can be easy or very complicated ( see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML );  as @cory mentioned above, what format/options are you attempting to replicate in R?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `jsonlite` package?

```
doc <- xmlParse( system.file("exampleData", "book.xml", package="XML"))
a <- xmlToList(doc)
jsonlite::toJSON(a, pretty=TRUE)
{
  "chapter": {
    "title": ["XML"],
    "section": {
      "title": ["The elements of an XML document"]
    },
    "section.1": {
      "title": ["Parsing XML"],
...

cat(RJSONIO::toJSON(a))
{
 "chapter": {
 "title": "XML",
"section": {
 "title": "The elements of an XML document" 
},
"section": {
 "title": "Parsing XML",
...
```